# check which button was clicked to change color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my problem, I create dynamic span in specif area thanks to "Link", "FirstName", "Lastname" buttons, and I would like to check which button was clicked among them in order to change color. For example, If I click the first time on "Link" button, the span is added in the area, and the "Link" button will become red. And if I click once again on it, the span will be removed, and the button will become grey.

```js
var area = document.getElementById("template");
var message = document.getElementById("message");
var maxLength = 160;
var re = new RegExp("ô|â|ê|ç");

var myTags = new Object();

myTags['company'] = '#ENTREPRISE#';
myTags['city'] = '#VILLE#';
myTags['link'] = '#LIEN#';
myTags['firstname'] = '#PRENOM#';
myTags['lastname'] = '#NOM#';
myTags['title'] = '#TITRE#';

function editTag(zoneId, tag, button) {
  var element = document.getElementById(button.id);
  var zoneDiv = document.getElementById(zoneId + 'Draft');
  var myButton = document.getElementById(zoneId + tag.ucfirst());
  var myLabel = document.createElement('span');

  var labels = zoneDiv.getElementsByTagName('span');
  var spanSize = labels.length;

  var delflag = 0;
  var delIndex = 0;

  if (spanSize != 0) {

    for (myLabId = 0; myLabId < spanSize; myLabId++) {
      var currentLabel = labels[myLabId];
      if (currentLabel.innerHTML === myButton.innerHTML) {
        delflag = 1;
        delIndex = myLabId;
      }
    }
  }

  if (delflag == 1) {
    zoneDiv.removeChild(labels[delIndex]);
    button.classList.toggle("btn-success");
  } else {
    myLabel.setAttribute('class', 'label label-info');
    myLabel.setAttribute('data-effect', 'pop');
    myLabel.setAttribute('contentEditable', 'false');
    myLabel.setAttribute('style', 'cursor:move;font-size:100%;');
    myLabel.setAttribute('name', tag);
    myLabel.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
    myLabel.innerHTML = myButton.innerHTML;

    zoneDiv.appendChild(myLabel);
    button.classList.toggle("btn-danger");
  }

  //Clean breaklines;
  var bks = zoneDiv.getElementsByTagName('br');
  var brSize = bks.length;

  if (brSize != 0) {
    zoneDiv.removeChild(bks[0]);
  }

  //Event keyboard on deleted elements
  $("span").dblclick(function(handler) {
    myLabel.remove(labels[delIndex]);
    
  });

}

function saveMessage(zoneId) {

  var zoneDiv = document.getElementById(zoneId + 'Draft');

  var message = zoneDiv.childNodes;
  var messSize = message.length;
  var messageContent = '';
  console.log(message);
  for (var messId = 0; messId < messSize; messId++) {
    var superRegex = /[a-zA-Z0-9áàâäãåçéèêëíìîïñóòôöõúùûüýÿæœÁÀÂÄÃÅÇÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÑÓÒÔÖÕÚÙÛÜÝŸÆŒ._\s\.\,\--]/g;
    if (zoneId === 'mail') {
      superRegex = /[a-zA-Z0-9áàâäãåçéèêëíìîïñóòôöõúùûüýÿæœÁÀÂÄÃÅÇÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÑÓÒÔÖÕÚÙÛÜÝŸÆŒ._\s\.\,\-\n-]/g;
    }

    if (message[messId].nodeName === '#text' && message[messId].nodeValue.match(superRegex))
    //  if(message[messId].nodeName === '#text' && message[messId].nodeValue.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9\,]/g) && message[messId].nodeValue.length < 100)
    {
      messageContent += message[messId].nodeValue;
    } else if (message[messId].nodeName === 'SPAN') {
      if (message[messId].getAttribute("name") == undefined) {
        continue;
      }

      //messageContent += myTags[message[messId].getAttribute("name")];
      var currentTag = '#' + message[messId].getAttribute("name").toUpperCase() + '#';
      messageContent += currentTag;
    } else if (message[messId].nodeName === 'IMG') {
      messageContent += message[messId].outerHTML;
    } else if (message[messId].nodeName === 'BR') {
      messageContent += message[messId].outerHTML;
    } else if (message[messId].nodeName === 'DIV') {
      messageContent += '<br>' + message[messId].innerHTML;
    }
  }

  var myRegexp = /\+/;
  messageContent.replace(myRegexp, '');

  if (zoneId === 'sms') {
    myRegexp = /\n/;
    messageContent.replace(myRegexp, '');
  }

  var idInput = document.getElementById('id');

  var myData = {
    'rm': 'saveMessage',
    'type': zoneId,
    'message': messageContent,
    'pid': idInput.getAttribute('value')
  };

  if (zoneId === 'mail') {
    var mySubject = document.getElementById('objectArea');

    myData = {
      'rm': 'saveMessage',
      'type': zoneId,
      'subject': mySubject.value,
      'mail': messageContent,
      'pid': idInput.getAttribute('value')
    };

    if (document.getElementById('mailType1').checked) {
      myData['mType'] = 'text';
    } else if (document.getElementById('mailType2').checked) {
      myData['mType'] = 'html';
    }
  }

  $.post("index.pl", myData).done(function(data) {
    window.alert(data);
  });
}

String.prototype.ucfirst = function() {
  return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.substr(1);
}

function previewMessage(zoneId) {
  var zoneDiv = document.getElementById(zoneId + 'Draft');

  var message = zoneDiv.childNodes;
  var messSize = message.length;
  var messageContent = '';

  var previewDiv = document.getElementById("preview");
  var mailPreview = document.getElementById('mailPreview');

  if (zoneId === 'sms') {
    previewDiv.setAttribute('style', '');
    previewDiv.innerHTML = '<p>Génération en cours ...</p>';
  } else if (zoneId === 'mail') {
    mailPreview.innerHTML = 'Génération en cours...';
  }

  for (var messId = 0; messId < messSize; messId++) {
    var superRegex = /[a-zA-Z0-9áàâäãåçéèêëíìîïñóòôöõúùûüýÿæœÁÀÂÄÃÅÇÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÑÓÒÔÖÕÚÙÛÜÝŸÆŒ._\s\.\,\--]/g;
    if (message[messId].nodeName === '#text' && message[messId].nodeValue.match(superRegex) && message[messId].nodeValue.length < 100)
    //if(message[messId].nodeName === '#text' && message[messId].nodeValue.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9\,]/g) && message[messId].nodeValue.length < 100)
    {
      messageContent += message[messId].nodeValue;
    } else if (message[messId].nodeName === 'SPAN' && message[messId].nodeName.innerHTML !== '') {
      if (message[messId].getAttribute("name") == undefined) {
        continue;
      }

      //messageContent += myTags[message[messId].getAttribute("name")];
      var currentTag = '#' + message[messId].getAttribute("name").toUpperCase() + '#';
      messageContent += currentTag;
    }
  }

  var myRegexp = /\+/;
  messageContent.replace(myRegexp, '');

  if (zoneId === 'sms') {
    myRegexp = /\n/;
    messageContent.replace(myRegexp, '');
  }

  var idInput = document.getElementById('id');

  var myData = {
    'rm': 'previewMessage',
    'type': zoneId,
    'message': btoa(messageContent),
    'pid': idInput.getAttribute('value')
  };


  if (zoneId === 'mail') {
    var mySubject = document.getElementById('objectArea');

    myData = {
      'rm': 'previewMessage',
      'type': zoneId,
      'subject': mySubject.value,
      'mail': btoa(messageContent),
      'pid': idInput.getAttribute('value')
    };
  }

  $.post("index.pl", myData).done(function(data) {
    if (zoneId === 'sms') {
      previewDiv.innerHTML = '';
      previewDiv.setAttribute("class", "preview");
      previewDiv.setAttribute("style", "background-image:url(/assets/img/smartphone_sms.png);width:435px;height:293px;");

      var myText = document.createElement('p');
      myText.setAttribute('class', 'smstext');
      myText.innerHTML = atob(data);
      //myText.innerHTML = data;
      previewDiv.appendChild(myText);
    } else {
      mailPreview.innerHTML = atob(data);
    }
  });
}

function testMessage(zoneId) {
  var costTestP = document.getElementById('costTest');
  costTestP.innerHTML = 'Calcul en cours ...';

  var zoneDiv = document.getElementById(zoneId + 'Area');

  var message = zoneDiv.childNodes;
  var messSize = message.length;
  var messageContent = '';

  for (var messId = 0; messId < messSize; messId++) {
    if (message[messId].nodeName === '#text' && message[messId].nodeValue.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9\,]/g) && message[messId].nodeValue.length < 100) {
      messageContent += message[messId].nodeValue;
    } else if (message[messId].nodeName === 'SPAN') {
      messageContent += myTags[message[messId].getAttribute("name")];
    }
  }

  var myRegexp = /\+/;
  messageContent.replace(myRegexp, '');

  myRegexp = /\n/;
  messageContent.replace(myRegexp, '');

  var idInput = document.getElementById('id');

  var myData = {
    'rm': 'testsms',
    'message': messageContent,
    'id': idInput.getAttribute('value')
  };

  $.post("index.pl", myData).done(function(data) {
    var costTestP = document.getElementById('costTest');
    costTestP.innerHTML = data;
  });
}

$('#smsDraft').on('dragstart', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.nodeName);
  if (e.target.nodeName !== 'SPAN') {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
});
```

```css
#smsArea {
  -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
  -webkit-appearance: textarea;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  resize: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.smstext {
  /*  margin-top: 100px;*/
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
}

#mailArea {
  -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
  -webkit-appearance: textarea;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  resize: both;
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.mailInput {
  -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
  -webkit-appearance: textarea;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  resize: both;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 85px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.mailtext {
  /*      margin-top: 100px;*/
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
}

#webtag {
  margin-top: -392px;
  margin-left: 555px;
  width: 569px;
}

#result {
  display: none;
}

#interaction {
  margin-top: 30px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#cd-popup {
  background-color: rgba(94, 110, 141, 0.9);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 4em auto;
  border-radius: .25em .25em .4em .4em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-40px);
  transform: translateY(-40px);
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  z-index: 1;
}

#cd-popup.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}

#cd-popup p {
  padding: 3em 1em;
  margin-left: -250px;
  height: 100px;
}

#cd-popup div {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

#object {
  background: #fc7169;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 .25em;
  width: 175px;
  margin-left: -400px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#object:hover {
  background-color: #fc8982;
}

#body {
  background: #6495ED;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 .25em;
  width: 175px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -150px;
}

#body:hover {
  background-color: #fc8982;
}

#titre {
  background: #A52A2A;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 .25em;
  width: 175px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#titre:hover {
  background-color: #fc8982;
}

#note {
  background: #006400;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 .25em;
  width: 175px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#cd-popup #note:hover {
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}

#cd-popup .cd-popup-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

#cd-popup .cd-popup-close::before,
#cd-popup .cd-popup-close::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #8f9cb5;
}

#cd-popup .cd-popup-close::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 8px;
}

#cd-popup .cd-popup-close::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 8px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  #cd-popup {
    margin: 8em auto;
  }
}

.webArea {
  -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
  -webkit-appearance: textarea;
  height: 520px;
  /*overflow: auto;*/
  padding: 5px;
  /*resize: both;*/
  width: 630px;
  font-size: 12px;
  /*margin-top: 55px;*/
  border: 2px dashed #D9D9D9;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 12%;
}

.webArea>div {
  background-color: #FAEBD7;
  border: 3px dashed #D9D9D9;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  height: 120px;
  width: 612px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /*    margin-left: -1.5%;*/
}

.webArea>div>div {
  transition: all .5s;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  /*background: #F7F7F7;*/
  transition: all .5s ease;
  width: 582px;
  /*background-color: #F8F8FF;*/
  height: 110px;
}

.dropTarget>div>div>span {
  font-style: italic;
  margin-right: 5%;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.webArea>div>div>input {
  margin-right: 25%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
}

.webArea>div>div:active {
  /*-webkit-animation: wiggle 0.3s 0s infinite ease-in;
    animation: wiggle 0.3s 0s infinite ease-in;*/
  opacity: .6;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

#mailArea {
  -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
  -webkit-appearance: textarea;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  resize: both;
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#containerZone {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
  */ margin: 3%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 8%;
  margin-left: -450px;
}

#containerZone2 {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 70%;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100%;
  margin-left: -450px;
}

#webtags {
  margin-top: -40px;
}

#webtags>div {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#modalTagBody {
  height: 120px;
}

#btnTag {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Drag & drop Tag</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mtb">
    <div class="row">
      <TMPL_IF NAME="PROFILE">
        <form role="form" action="<TMPL_VAR NAME=MYURL>?rm=saveTemplate" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
          <TMPL_LOOP NAME="DATA">
            <input type="hidden" id='id' name="id" value="<TMPL_VAR NAME=ID>" />
            <TMPL_IF NAME="TEMPLATE">
              <div class="panel panel-primary" id="panels" data-effect="helix">
                <div class="panel-heading">SMS Message</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="saveTemplate" />
                    <div id="smsArea" class="form-control" contenteditable="true">
                      <p id="smsDraft">
                        <TMPL_VAR NAME=TEMPLATE>
                      </p>
                    </div><br />
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="saveMessage('sms');">Save</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="previewMessage('sms');" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Preview</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="testMessage('sms');" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">SMS Costs</a>
                    <br>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6" id='smsTags'>
                    <h4 for="template">Personnalization</h4>
                    <span class="btn btn-default" onClick="editTag('sms','link', this)" id="smsLink" title="link of your website" draggable="true">Link</span>
                    <span class="btn btn-default" onClick="editTag('sms','firstname')" id="smsFirstname" title="your firstname" draggable="true">Firstname</span>
                    <span class="btn btn-default" onClick="editTag('sms','lastname')" id="smsLastname" title="your lastname" draggable="true">Lastname</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6" style="margin-top: 30px">
                  </div>
                </div>
          </TMPL_LOOP>
          </div>
          <! --/row -->
    </div>
    <! --/container -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please replace the TMPL code with a minimum of actual HTML in a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass reference of clicked button using 'this' e.g 
onClick = "editTag('sms','link', this)"

Once you get refrence of clicked element in onClick function, you can access the same element and toggle css class(class for red color)

```
function editTag(zoneId, tag, elementRef) {
    // Check if function has received element refrence and toggle class
    if(elementRef){
        var element = document.getElementById(elementRef.id);
        element.classList.toggle("btn-danger")
    }
    var zoneDiv = document.getElementById(zoneId + 'Draft');
    var myButton = document.getElementById(zoneId + tag.ucfirst());
    var myLabel = document.createElement('span');
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but maybe I made a mistake, now if I click on "Link" button, the button is red, but If I click once again on "Link" button, he stays red. Green displays when I click for the third time :/

Comment: What do you mean? I edited the actual code in the snippet

Comment: Yes,it will work perfect, you just need to place button.classList.toggle("btn-danger"); and button.classList.toggle("btn-success"); at right place

Comment: According to me, I put them at the right place in editTag() function, but I still get the problem for the display in green of the button

Comment: could you please make your requirement clear, when you want it red, green and grey.

Comment: Oh ok no problem, so I want red button when the span is added in the area(when you click on "Link" button), green button when the span is removed(when you click once again on "Link" button) and grey is the default color of the button.

Comment: if (delflag == 1) {
   . 
   .
    button.classList.add("btn-success");
    button.classList.remove("btn-danger");
  } else {
     .
     .
    button.classList.add("btn-danger");
    button.classList.remove("btn-success");
  }